# In Schrödinger's equation, well-behaved wave functions at $t=0$ changing their normalization value

Tags: partial-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics, initial-value-problems

In Schrödinger's equation well-behaved wave functions at $t=0$ will never change their normalization value no matter what the real valued potential $V(x,t)$ is.

So, I have a counter example for this:

$$\varphi(x,t)=\sqrt{{\Big(\frac{t}{a}\Big)}^2+1}\,\,\frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}{2b^2}}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}\,\,b}}\exp\left\{i\left\{\frac{-2mt}{\hbar(t^2+a^2)}\int_0^xe^{\frac{l^2}{b^2}}\int_0^le^{\frac{-n^2}{b^2}}\,\,dn\,\,dl\right\}\right\},$$

where $a$ , $b$ , $\hbar$ and $m$ are real values greater than $0$.
If we put this complex function which is smooth in the equation

$$i\hbar\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t}=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2 \varphi}{\partial x^2}+V(x,t)\varphi, $$

we will get a real valued function $V(x,t)$, that is, the imaginary part of $V$ cancels out. Furthermore at $t=0$,

$$\varphi(x)=\frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}{2b^2}}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}\,\,b}}$$

which I think is a very well behaved wave function, but it’s changing its normalization value $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\varphi|^2\,\,dx$ through time for the real $V(x,t)$ that we get.

**Questions**

1. What is happening? Is there a mathematical constraint on what $V(x,t)$ should be for the normalization value to be indepentent of time?
2. The normalization value will also change no matter what $V(x,t)$ is, for some smooth initial wavefunctions?

**Edit**: Any one trying to work this one out? When I try to put this into the equation it is checking out. I really am getting a real valued potential.

**Computation**:

We can write the given wavefunction in the form

$$\varphi(x,t)=A(x,t)e^{i\theta(x,t)},$$
where
$$A(x,t)=\sqrt{{\Big(\frac{t}{a}\Big)}^2+1}\,\,\frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}{2b^2}}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}\,\,b}}$$
and
$$\theta(x,t)=\frac{-2mt}{\hbar(t^2+a^2)}\int_0^xe^{\frac{l^2}{b^2}}\int_0^le^{\frac{-n^2}{b^2}}\,\,dn\,\,dl$$

so in the equation,
$$i\hbar\frac{\partial Ae^{i\theta}}{\partial t}+\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2 Ae^{i\theta}}{\partial x^2}=VAe^{i\theta}$$

$$i\hbar\left\{iAe^{i\theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}+e^{i\theta}\frac{\partial A}{\partial t}\right\}+\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left\{iAe^{i\theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}+e^{i\theta}\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}\right\}=VAe^{i\theta}$$

$$i\hbar\left\{iAe^{i\theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}+e^{i\theta}\frac{\partial A}{\partial t}\right\}+\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left\{e^{i\theta}\left\{iA\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}\right\}\right\}=VAe^{i\theta}$$

$$i\hbar\left\{iAe^{i\theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}+e^{i\theta}\frac{\partial A}{\partial t}\right\}+\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left\{ie^{i\theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}\left\{iA\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}\right\}+e^{i\theta}\left\{i\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x }+iA\frac{\partial^2 \theta}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 A}{\partial x^2}\right\}\right\}=VAe^{i\theta}$$

now we can take $e^{i\theta}$ common outside and cancel both sides,

$$i\hbar\left\{iA\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial A}{\partial t}\right\}+\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left\{i\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}\left\{iA\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}\right\}+\left\{i\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x }+iA\frac{\partial^2 \theta}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 A}{\partial x^2}\right\}\right\}=VA$$

$$-\hbar A\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}+i\hbar\frac{\partial A}{\partial t}+\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left\{-A{\Big(\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}\Big)}^2+i\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x }+iA\frac{\partial^2 \theta}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 A}{\partial x^2}\right\}=VA$$

$$-\hbar A\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}+i\hbar\frac{\partial A}{\partial t}+\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left\{-A{\Big(\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}\Big)}^2+2i\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}+iA\frac{\partial^2 \theta}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 A}{\partial x^2}\right\}=VA$$

$$\frac{1}{A}\left\{i\hbar\frac{\partial A}{\partial t}+\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left\{2i\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}+iA\frac{\partial^2 \theta}{\partial x^2}\right\}-\hbar A\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}+\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left\{-A{\Big(\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}\Big)}^2+\frac{\partial^2 A}{\partial x^2}\right\}\right\}=V$$

we can see that imaginary part of V is,

$$\frac{1}{A}\left\{i\hbar\frac{\partial A}{\partial t}+\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left\{2i\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}+iA\frac{\partial^2 \theta}{\partial x^2}\right\}\right\}$$

we can take i common and multiply and divide by 2A so we get,

$$\frac{i}{2A^2}\left\{\hbar(2A)\frac{\partial A}{\partial t}+\frac{\hbar^2}{m}\left\{2A\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}+A^2\frac{\partial^2 \theta}{\partial x^2}\right\}\right\}$$

so we can write is as,

$$\frac{i}{2A^2}\left\{\hbar\frac{\partial A^2}{\partial t}+\frac{\hbar^2}{m}\left\{\frac{\partial A^2}{\partial x}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}+A^2\frac{\partial^2 \theta}{\partial x^2}\right\}\right\}$$

we can see that in the second term its a multiplication rule so,

$$\frac{i\hbar}{2A^2}\left\{\frac{\partial A^2}{\partial t}+\frac{\hbar}{m}\frac{\partial A^2\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}}{\partial x}\right\}$$

so this is the imaginary part,
now compute $A^2\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}$,
$$A^2\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}=\left\{{\Big(\frac{t}{a}\Big)}^2+1\right\}\,\,\frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}{b^2}}}{\sqrt{\pi}\,\,b}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left\{\frac{-2mt}{\hbar(t^2+a^2)}\int_0^xe^{\frac{l^2}{b^2}}\int_0^le^{\frac{-n^2}{b^2}}\,\,dn\,\,dl\right\}$$

you can take the term dependent upon time outside,
$$A^2\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}=\left\{{\Big(\frac{t}{a}\Big)}^2+1\right\}\,\,\frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}{b^2}}}{\sqrt{\pi}\,\,b}\Big(\frac{-2mt}{\hbar(t^2+a^2)}\Big)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left\{\int_0^xe^{\frac{l^2}{b^2}}\int_0^le^{\frac{-n^2}{b^2}}\,\,dn\,\,dl\right\}$$

you can easily differentiate it now,
$$A^2\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}=\left\{{\Big(\frac{t}{a}\Big)}^2+1\right\}\,\,\frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}{b^2}}}{\sqrt{\pi}\,\,b}\Big(\frac{-2mt}{\hbar(t^2+a^2)}\Big)e^{\frac{x^2}{b^2}}\int_0^xe^{\frac{-n^2}{b^2}}\,\,dn$$

$$A^2\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}=\frac{(t^2+a^2)}{a^2}\,\,\frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}{b^2}}}{\sqrt{\pi}\,\,b}\Big(\frac{-2mt}{\hbar(t^2+a^2)}\Big)e^{\frac{x^2}{b^2}}\int_0^xe^{\frac{-n^2}{b^2}}\,\,dn$$

$$A^2\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}=\frac{-2mt}{\hbar a^2b\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^xe^{\frac{-n^2}{b^2}}\,\,dn$$

now if we differentiate with respect to x again,
$$\frac{\partial A^2\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}}{\partial x}=\frac{-2mt}{\hbar a^2b\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\partial \int_0^xe^{\frac{-n^2}{b^2}}\,\,dn}{\partial x}$$

$$\frac{\partial A^2\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}}{\partial x}=\frac{-2mt}{\hbar a^2b\sqrt{\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{b^2}}$$

so ,
$$\frac{\hbar}{m}\frac{\partial A^2\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}}{\partial x}=\frac{-2t}{a^2b\sqrt{\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{b^2}},$$

now try to compute $\frac{\partial A^2}{\partial t}$ we get,

$$\frac{\partial A^2}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left\{\frac{(t^2+a^2)e^{\frac{-x^2}{b^2}}}{a^2b\sqrt{\pi}}\right\}$$

this is,

$$\frac{\partial A^2}{\partial t}=\frac{2te^{\frac{-x^2}{b^2}}}{a^2b\sqrt{\pi}}$$

we can see that $\frac{\partial A^2}{\partial t}$ and $\frac{\hbar}{m}\frac{\partial A^2\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}}{\partial x}$ both cancel eachother,

and therefore making the imaginary part $0$.

Comment: Fixed Normalization is ensured by direct integration of $\partial_t \bar \psi \psi$ over space. If this integral doesn't converge, the assumption fails. Try calculating $\int dx \partial_t \bar \psi \psi$ and see if it zero.

Comment: By ensured you mean that we have to satisfy the condition of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\partial |\varphi|^2}{\partial t}\,\,dx=0$ over the Schrodinger equation to get good wavefunctions. Because Schrodinger equation is not enough alone to fix the normalisation as that can be seen in the question.

Comment: I mean that that condition can be derived from the Sch. equation by integration by parts.

Comment: No isn't that what is being disproved here. The counter example that satisfies the Schrodinger equation that isn't normalised. You can put the wave function into the equation and get a real valued potential function of x and t. So that means that for that potential function the wave function satisfies the equation . So Schrodinger equation does not fix the normalisation integral on its own.

Comment: it does, due to unitarity of the dynamics. I suspect an error

Comment: You can check it in mathlab.it checks out. The imaginary part of the potential function goes to zero therefore getting a real potential function. And also in the proof of Schrodinger equation normalisation there is an assumption that is made.

Comment: All I mean is that there exists a real valued function $V(x,t)$ that with the function $\varphi(x,t)$ that is given in the question will satisfy the Schrodinger equation. That's all.

Comment: what is $\phi(x,t)$ here?

Comment: I actually am coming up with the computation as we speak. so if there are any errors in that. we will see.

Comment: well can you spot an errors in any step?? also what did you get your imaginary part

Comment: Ok sorry, I think your calculations are correct. I spotted a mistake in my calculation and now it seems it’s all working. I’m deleting previous comments. I’ll think about your question. In any case, it seems to me that this phenomenon is due to the very highly oscillatory phase $e^{i\theta}$, which makes space and time derivatives grow very fast as $x\to\pm\infty$.

Comment: Thanks. I will be waiting for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The potential being real valued is not enough to preserv the normalization, you also need some condition on $\pm \infty$. Notice that your solution oscillates wildly as $x\rightarrow \pm \infty$. The proof typicaly relies on the formula
$$ \partial_t(\lvert \phi \rvert^2) = \frac{i\hbar}{2m}(\phi^*\phi_{xx} - \phi \phi^*_{xx}),$$
and after integrating in $\mathbb R$ and using integration by parts everything cancels and the norm is preserv, but this is true only if the boundary terms vanish, namely

$$\frac{d}{dt} \int_{\Bbb R } \lvert \phi \rvert^2 \, dx = -\frac{i\hbar}{2m} \int_{\Bbb R} \phi^*_x \phi_x - \phi_x \phi^*_x + \frac{i\hbar}{2m} \left \{ \lim_{x\to \infty}\phi^*(x) \phi_x(x) - \lim_{x\to -\infty}\phi^*(x) \phi_x(x) - \lim_{x\to \infty}\phi(x)\phi^*_x(x)+\lim_{x\to \infty}\phi(x) \phi^*_x(x) \right \}$$
And for your solution those limits probably don't vanish.

Comment: ok I see that $A^2\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}$ is not vanishing as $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$ for all t .$$$$
so any two good smooth functions $\varphi(x,t)$(complex function which is normalizable at all t and is non trivial) and $V(x,t)$(real function) that satisfy both condidtions, the sch equation and ($\varphi^*\partial_x\varphi \rightarrow 0$ and $\varphi\partial_x\varphi^* \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$ for all t)  will maintain the normalization value and "also will represent a valid quantum mechanical situation". Is the latter part true also?

Comment: thinking on the quantum mechanics further it feels like a game of chicken and egg like which came first chicken or the egg. in quantum mechanics case the chicken and egg refers to the so called space of all linear Hermitian operators and  the state space of wave functions. like you can't define one thing without the other, its really crazy.